# Problem showing a shape on a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have designed a navigation bar, which has a title in the middle and 2 arrows on each side

so far this is my code:

```css
.TopNav {
  width: 1119px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FAF7FC;
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.arrowR .arrowL {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(18, 0, 94, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowL {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrowR {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.arrowL:hover .arrowR:hover {
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(18, 0, 94, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="TopNav col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="content">
      <p id="name">
        This Week
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowR"></div>
    <div class="arrowL"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This only shows the rectangle (the main bar) and the title, but does not display the arrows. what is the problem, and how can I put the arrows on each side of the bar?

Answer (score 0):

You made small mistake. You forget to add comma between two classes. And some other issue. I try to fix that. Please check below code snippet.

```css
.TopNav {
    width: 1119px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FAF7FC;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #name {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  .arrowR, .arrowL {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 15px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(18, 0, 94, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .arrowL {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .arrowR {
    left: auto;
    right: 15px;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  
  .arrowL:hover, .arrowR:hover {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(18, 0, 94, 1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="TopNav col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="content">
      <p id="name">
        This Week
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowR"></div>
    <div class="arrowL"></div>
  </div>
```